# Unable to check whether a given number is integer or not. (using scanf return value)

Tags: c, integer, scanf

```
int getvalue(int *arr_value, int number)
{
    int i = 0;
    int temp =0;
    while(i < number)
    {
        if((scanf("%d",temp)) == 1) // to check whether input is integer 
        {
            arr_value[i++] = temp; // to store it in array only if it is int
        }
        else
        {   
            printf("\n Enter a proper integer: "); 
            continue;// go to the loop again to prompt value from user
        }
    }
    for(i =0 ; i < number; i++)
    {
         printf("%d",arr_value[i]);
    }
 }
 /* this program runs the enter integer line infinitely, 
    although I tried it with a continue statement.*/
```

Comment: Once the input fails, it will fail continuously.  The input isn't acceptable as an integer — it stays unacceptable as an integer.  You must do something to change the state of the input.  Commonly, that is 'read and ignore characters up to the next newline (or EOF)': `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;`.

Comment: You cannot `scanf("%d"...)` a non-integer value. The function (`scanf`) will just return 0 (number of values scanned from `stdin`) when you do that.

Comment: Replace `temp` with '&temp' inside `scanf`. Also as @barakmanos said, `scanf` returns the number of scanned values. Positive return value doesnt mean that the value scanned is an integer

Comment: Is there any other way to check whether the given input is integer ??